# Removing parent elements and re-appending children

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, append, detach

I have a navigation that's a unordered list, here's the simple structure I'm following / have to follow for my jQuery plugin to work correctly, therefore making this code structure a necessity:

```
<nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu">
<div class="mp-level">
    <ul id="demo1" class="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Devices</a>
            <div class="mp-level">
            <h2>Devices</h2>
            <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Mobile Phones</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Televisions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cameras</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Magazines</a>
            <div class="mp-level">
                <h2>Magazines</h2>
                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">National Geographic</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Scientific American</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        ...
   </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

I need to provide a fallback and I have selected another jQuery plugin that needs to use a different structure to the above. I need to remove the DIV's with classname `.mp-level` but still keeping all unordered lists including `.mp-level` child lists.

The result will just be unordered lists without headings and DIV'S. My code below is removing the correct elements but my issue is with re-inserting the child unordered lists (specifically level 2):

```
$( "#demo1 h2, .mp-back" ).remove();
$( ".mp-level ul li .mp-level" ).detach();
$( ".mp-level ul li" ).append('.mp-level ul li .mp-level ul');
```

**Anyone got any advice how to re-insert child UL's after I have removed their parents**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

```
$("#mp-menu").find(".mp-level").each(function(i,n){//each ".mp-level"
    $(n).parent().append($(n).children());//append children to parent
    $(n).remove();//remove actual div
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WBWwG/

Answer (score 0):

You can save the detached nodes (wrapped inside a jQuery object) by assigning them to a variable and then using that variable in the `.append()` call.

Something like this:

```
// this selector doesn't select anything from the example html, btw
var $mp_level = $( ".mp-level ul li .mp-level" ).detach(); 
$(".mp-level ul li").append($mp_level);
```

Comment: Your very first answer before the edits was working but it duplicated the data for the first child UL for every child UL that existed. The second and third edit don't seem to work for me

Comment: I see. I guess i'm a little confused about the your snippet's goal (-:. I'm glad you got an answer anyway.